# Flash builder can't generate arm64 only build

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder

We use `Flash Builder` for app development. Need to generate a release build that supports only `arm64`, which means it will prevent users to install our app if their device is not for `arm64`.

We did use `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` to specify the limitation the in the description xml:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array><string>arm64</string></array>
```

However, when we submitted the build to iTunes, we got this error: Apps that have `arm64` in the list of `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` in `info.plist` must only contain the `arm64` slice.

From our research, it seems that if we are using XCode, there is an option to select the architecture for `arm64` only(xcode - How to submit an archive only for 64-bit iOS devices? - Stack Overflow ). But we are using Flash builder. How to make FB compile the code for `arm64` only?

We don't use any ANEs. Just our own as3 classes. We are using `Flash builder 4.6`, and `air sdk 24`.

Thanks a lot for your tips!

J.T